# Is there any example how to use Matrix Toolkit Java (MTJ)?

Tags: java, matrix

I am having trouble figuring out how to use Matrix Toolkit Java from the Javadocs.

Do there exist code examples for MTJ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you come across this:http://code.google.com/p/matrix-toolkits-java/wiki/Overview ?

Comment: Yes, I have read it, but there is few code example.